# Limiting XSLT text extraction to specific fields

Tags: xml, xslt, text, extract

Still pretty new to XSLT; I'm trying to extract certain fields, and only certain fields from an XML file using XSLT (1.0).  Here's a simplified form of the actual XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transaction>
  <TradeMarkTransactionBody>
    <TransactionContentDetails>
      <TransactionCode>National Trademark Information</TransactionCode>
      <TransactionData>
        <TradeMarkDetails>
          <TradeMark>
            <RegistrationOfficeCode>US</RegistrationOfficeCode>
            <ApplicationNumber>74631225</ApplicationNumber>
            <ApplicationDate>1995-02-07-05:00</ApplicationDate>
            <RegistrationNumber>2178784</RegistrationNumber>
            <RegistrationDate>1998-08-04-04:00</RegistrationDate>
            <FilingPlace>US</FilingPlace>
            <MarkCurrentStatusDate>2008-08-11-04:00</MarkCurrentStatusDate>
            <WordMarkSpecification>
              <MarkVerbalElementText>JAVA </MarkVerbalElementText>
            </WordMarkSpecification>
          </TradeMark>
        </TradeMarkDetails>
      </TransactionData>
    </TransactionContentDetails>
  </TradeMarkTransactionBody>
</Transaction>
```

Here's my XSLT attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Transaction">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TradeMark">
MarkCurrentStatusDate,"<xsl:value-of select="MarkCurrentStatusDate"/>"
ApplicationNumber,"<xsl:value-of select="ApplicationNumber"/>"
ApplicationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="ApplicationDate"/>"
RegistrationNumber,"<xsl:value-of select="RegistrationNumber"/>"
RegistrationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="RegistrationDate"/>"
ExpirationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="ExpirationDate"/>"
<xsl:apply-templates select="WordMarkSpecification"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="WordMarkSpecification">
MarkVerbalElementText,"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(MarkVerbalElementText)"/>"
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which nearly works, resulting in:

```
National Trademark Information
MarkCurrentStatusDate,"2008-08-11-04:00"
ApplicationNumber,"74631225"
ApplicationDate,"1995-02-07-05:00"
RegistrationNumber,"2178784"
RegistrationDate,"1998-08-04-04:00"
ExpirationDate,""

MarkVerbalElementText,"JAVA"
```

My questions: 1) how can I avoid picking up the unwanted data like `TransactionCode` ("`National Trademark Information`" in the output); and 2) how do I avoid the blank line between `ExpirationDate` and `MarkVerbalElementText`?  (I've confirmed that its not the blank lines in the XSLT file; leaving them out does not have an effect.)

(I suspect that these two questions may have a single answer; that I am somehow preserving not-selected `MarkVerbalElementText` text, *and* some not-selected line breaks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Your first template "consumes" the entire document, and if you want only the `TradeMark` tags, simply apply only to the tags of interest.

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//TradeMark"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I found that addressed the extraction, and with some experimentation with <xsl:text/> (which I pulled from the XSLT Cookbook, but will have to read up on to understand), was able to get rid of the blanks, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (somewhat convoluted) pull approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:util="urn:util">

    <xsl:output
        method="text" 
        encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="document('')/*/util:fields"/>
    <util:fields>
        <field>MarkCurrentStatusDate</field>
        <field>ApplicationNumber</field>
        <field>ApplicationDate</field>
        <field>RegistrationNumber</field>
        <field>RegistrationDate</field>
        <field>ExpirationDate</field>
        <field>MarkVerbalElementText</field>
    </util:fields>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="xml" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields/field">
            <xsl:variable name="f" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$f"/>
            <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($xml//TradeMark//*[local-name() = $f])"/>
            <xsl:text>"&#x000A;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It results in the following output using Saxon 6.5.5, Saxon-EE 9.4.0.3, and xsltproc with libxml/20708 and libxslt/10126:

```
MarkCurrentStatusDate="2008-08-11-04:00"
ApplicationNumber="74631225"
ApplicationDate="1995-02-07-05:00"
RegistrationNumber="2178784"
RegistrationDate="1998-08-04-04:00"
ExpirationDate=""
MarkVerbalElementText="JAVA"
```

I am not too confident of it holding up past the sample XML you provided, but it does work there.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is a slight correction and simplification (one unnecessary template is removed) of the provided transformation -- now producing the wanted, correct result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="TradeMark">
    MarkCurrentStatusDate,"<xsl:value-of select="MarkCurrentStatusDate"/>"
    ApplicationNumber,"<xsl:value-of select="ApplicationNumber"/>"
    ApplicationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="ApplicationDate"/>"
    RegistrationNumber,"<xsl:value-of select="RegistrationNumber"/>"
    RegistrationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="RegistrationDate"/>"
    ExpirationDate,"<xsl:value-of select="ExpirationDate"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="WordMarkSpecification"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="WordMarkSpecification">
    MarkVerbalElementText,"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(MarkVerbalElementText)"/>"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TransactionCode"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Transaction>
    <TradeMarkTransactionBody>
        <TransactionContentDetails>
            <TransactionCode>National Trademark Information</TransactionCode>
            <TransactionData>
                <TradeMarkDetails>
                    <TradeMark>
                        <RegistrationOfficeCode>US</RegistrationOfficeCode>
                        <ApplicationNumber>74631225</ApplicationNumber>
                        <ApplicationDate>1995-02-07-05:00</ApplicationDate>
                        <RegistrationNumber>2178784</RegistrationNumber>
                        <RegistrationDate>1998-08-04-04:00</RegistrationDate>
                        <FilingPlace>US</FilingPlace>
                        <MarkCurrentStatusDate>2008-08-11-04:00</MarkCurrentStatusDate>
                        <WordMarkSpecification>
                            <MarkVerbalElementText>JAVA </MarkVerbalElementText>
                        </WordMarkSpecification>
                    </TradeMark>
                </TradeMarkDetails>
            </TransactionData>
        </TransactionContentDetails>
    </TradeMarkTransactionBody>
</Transaction>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
MarkCurrentStatusDate,"2008-08-11-04:00"
ApplicationNumber,"74631225"
ApplicationDate,"1995-02-07-05:00"
RegistrationNumber,"2178784"
RegistrationDate,"1998-08-04-04:00"
ExpirationDate,""
MarkVerbalElementText,"JAVA"
```

**Explanation**:

1. The empty-bodied template:

   `<xsl:template match="TransactionCode"/>`

   serves to override the XSLT built-in template matching an element, that produces the concatenation of all text-node descendants of the matched element.
2. The `<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>` on the end of the line prevents the following new-line character to be interpreted as part of the desired output, thus the observed empty line is eliminated.
3. The template matching `Transaction` is removed, since it behaves exactly as the XSLT built-in template that matches an element -- applies templates to all of its children.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll compare both of the answers (both work) and hope to get a better understanding of the approaches.  I found I actually had 3 blank lines, but by putting  </xsl:text> at the start of the MarkCurrentStatusDate select and end of the last select in each template, I was able to suppress all.

Comment: Dimitre, if I understand the approach you suggest, I need to specify the elements not to extract, correct?  Since this is a simplified example, in a fuller one with many other elements, I would need to add a null template for each, right?

Comment: @user1564935, You are welcome. The answer that you accepted doesn't solve your empty-line problem. Also it is in "pull style", while this answer is in pure "push style". "Push style" transformations are recommended over "pull style" ones due to greater flexibility/extensibility/maintainability.

Comment: @user1564935, No, in most cases you can combine any set of element names and specify them in a single template.

Comment: But each element I want to ignore must be identified, right?  That will get kind of hairy in the non-simplified one.  I'm actually throwing away something like 80% and only keeping a few data.

Comment: @user1564935, As I said, in most cases all unwanted elements can be specified in the match pattern of a single template. This isn't a "hairy" situation. You can either edit your question and provide more representative data, or you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that.  It's not the number of templates that concerns me, it's the necessity to specify all the data that I need to ignore, just to ignore it.  The problems I foresee here is the danger of missing one; the additional complexity of testing; and potential fragility as an additional element not previously used often (and missed in testing) gets used.  Since there's only a small subset of data that I actually want to process, I think in my case, a solution that specifies the data that I want to extract, rather than all the data I don't care about, is best solution for me.

Comment: @user1564935, In many cases we can avoid specifying all element names to be ignored -- we can just specify the few element names that we are interested in.

Comment: @user1564935, In case you bother to edit the question and provide a more realistic example, or do this in a new, separate question, I will show you that it may not be necessary to provide all the unwanted element names in order to exclude them -- seeing is believing.